# Distinguishing between multiple table model listeners

Tags: java, swing

I have 3 tables with all of the same column identifiers. My controller is listening to all three of their models. Is there a more elegant way of identifying which model fired the event other than changing the table layout (prefix table name in one of the column names for example)?

Here is my current working implementation:

```
/**
 * Enter here with every edit of the 3 tables
 */
public static class TableListener implements TableModelListener {

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) { 
        int row;
        int column;

        if (e.getSource() instanceof TableModel) { 
                TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource(); // Cast to known model
                row = e.getFirstRow();
                column = e.getColumn();

                String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
                Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You could pass something to the TableListener class in the constructor to distinguish between the 3 table models.

Comment: If you have 3 different tables and you want to react in 3 different manners to TableModelEvent, then consider creating 3 different TableModelListener. This will simplify your code and avoid confusion.